# How to reconstruct a String correctly from a String which be encoded by wrong charset

Tags: matlab, encoding, urlread

**Edit** Added some new information to make the question more clearly.

In matlab early before 2012B, the method `urlread` would return a string constructed by wrong charset if the web content's charset is not utf8. (It has been improved somewhat in Matlab 2012B)

For example

```
% a chinese website whose content encoding by gb2312
url = 'http://www.cnbeta.com/articles/213618.htm'; 
html = urlread(url)
```

Because Matlab encoded the html using utf8 instead of gb2312.
You will see the chinese character in the html doesnot show correctly.

If I read a chinese website with utf8 encoded, then everything works fine:

```
% a chinese website whose content encoding by utf8
url = 'http://www.baidu.com/'; 
html = urlread(url)
```

So is there any way to reconstruct the string correctly from html?
I have tried as  following, but it didnot work:

```
>> bytes = unicode2native(html,'utf8');
>> str = native2unicode(bytes,'gb2312')
```

However, I do known there is a way to fix the `urlread`'s problem: 
Type `edit urlread.m` in the console and then replace the code nearly Line 108 (In matlab 2011B):

```
output = native2unicode(typecast(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray','uint8'),'UTF-8');
```

by:

```
output = native2unicode(typecast(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray','uint8'),'gb2312');
```

Save the file, and now `urlread` would works for website encoded by gb2312.
Actually, this solution point out why `urlread` doesnot work sometime. The method `urlread` always use the utf8 charset to encode string even if the content is not encoded by utf8.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It seems that you already have the solution, just create a function called urlread_gb that can read gb2312.

Comment: well boys, same question here... It is possible to make this kind of conversions in a more 'better' way?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have the solution, just create a function called `urlread_gb` that can read `gb2312`.